# How to give zooming of iPhone Camera feature in an app?

Tags: iphone

I have to give a zooming feature to an iPhone Camera in my app. Camera should be zoom up to 1X using slider. I didn't find any property or function in UIImagePickerControllerDelegate. How it can be done? Is there any sample code available from in the Apple Documentation? 
Thanks-